# Can we say that $X=\{x_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ with $x_m=\sum_{i=1}^{m}(\frac{1}{i})$ is totally disconnected?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $X=\{x_n\}_{n\in
\mathbb{Z}}$ where for $m\in\mathbb{N}$,  $x_m=\sum_{i=1}^{m}(\frac{1}{i})$ and $x_{-m}= \sum_{i=-m}^{0}(\frac{1}{i-1})$ given the
metric inherited from $\mathbb{R}$.

Can I say that $X$ is totally disconnected?

Comment: Do you know the definition of totally disconnectedness? Have you tried applying it to $X$?

Comment: @TheoBendit, I think that the only connected sets are singletons

Answer (score 2):

Any countable subset of $\Bbb R$ is totally disconnected. So yours is too.